# navigate to back page in page based interface on event programmatically

Tags: objective-c, interface, navigation, watchkit

My application is page based, i want on one event my app swipe to left page programmatically.i tried using becomeCurrentPage method but how to use it in this case.
please  help.
any suggestions  will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`becomeCurrentPage` is the only way to programmatically change the current page, so you're on the right track. However, it sounds like you need to communicate from one page to another.

Assuming your interface controller knows its own page index (which you can pass to `awakeWithContext:`), you can accomplish this by sending a custom notification:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ @"page" : @(MAX(self.pageIndex - 1, 0)) };
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyChangePageNotification"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];
```

Then, in each controller, make sure you're listening for the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserverForName:@"MyChangePageNotification"
 object:nil
 queue:nil
 usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

     // Are we supposed to become the current page?
     if (self.pageIndex == [note.userInfo[@"page"] integerValue]) {
         [self becomeCurrentPage];
     }
 }];
```

Basically, each page listens for your custom notification, and when the passed page index matches the controller's index, it becomes the current page.